# exe without console window, without visual studio

Tags: console, hide, exe

Firstly, I am not using visual studio, I am using notepad and csc. What I am trying to do is create exe's like visual studio's Windows Applications, that is, that do not open any console window at all when you double click the exe. I have found this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32"]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

IntPtr window = GetConsoleWindow();
if(window != IntPtr.Zero) ShowWindow(window, 0);
```

and similar snippets, which work but the console still shows up for a split-second. I want it to not show up at all.

Also, using the Process class does not help because the exe is standalone and is to be double-clicked by hand, it is not launched from an already-running program.

I am also aware of using a vbs script to launch a bat that opens the exe, and other workarounds, but they do not suit my needs.

How can I compile the exe to merely open without any console window at all? It must be possible because visual studio's Windows Applications do it. To clarify I don't even want a form, I just want the program to run in the background, I only am referring to Windows Applications for the sake of comparison since they show no console.

Please don't give me any stupid answers like "use visual studio" or respond with a question instead of an answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use the unmanaged library kernel32.dll and the FreeConsole function.  Here is an example:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool FreeConsole();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FreeConsole();
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for!

Comment: Hi, that appears to be identical in function to the snippet I posted, i.e. I tried it and the console window still comes up for a moment before closing. It makes sense that this would occur because the exe itself is loaded and launched, with the console, before that line of code (FreeConsole) is ever hit. Therefore I believed that I need to compile the exe differently, the way visual studio does it for Windows Applications. Do you have any other suggestions how I might do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can go only one way.

1. Create your (own) application as GUI subsystem, rather CONSOLE subsystem.
2. When you run compilers - use CreateProcess or ShellExecute (C++) with SW_HIDE (CmdShow). Can't remember, is there corresponding argument in C# function, thought - must be. If not - use WinAPI to start compiler.

This method will completely obscure console window.